# Configuration Metadata for Spring Cloud AWS - i.e. Autocomplete in YML / .properties

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-aws

Does Spring Cloud AWS provide any sort of configuration metadata for the `cloud.aws` family of properties? (i.e. for *cloud.aws.region.static*)

Would be great to be able to get some auto-completion when setting configuration in `application.properties|yml`, but I have not come across any when working with the different libs.

Comment: not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, 
I ended up just adding an entry to `META-INF/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json` and all is well.
 Appreciate the work you all put in over @ Pivotal 